# C# Structure to act like an object cache

Tags: c#, data-structures, structure

I'm searching for a generic structure thaht would allow me to give a number of items to hold. Then, every time I add an item to this list, the oldest item(the one that has the oldest access) would be removed to keep an item with a fixed size.

Every item would have an key(in my case datetime, but this should be generic).

This structure could even have only one method: `TItem Get(TKey key)`, but we would have to provide a delegate to retrieve the value if it's not yet in cache.

Are you aware of such structure? Ideally existing in .Net 4.5 ?

I'm aware of the `MemoryCache` but:

- I didn't found how to have a specific number of items
- It seems that the key has to be a string
- It's not generic

It has to be a better class doing that, no? I could certainly do one myself, but I don't want to reinvent the wheel and it will take me some trials to have something really efficient.

Comment: If the structure only has one method 'Get', how do you ever add anything to it?

Comment: How about a circular buffer? Very efficient for multi-threaded environments.

Comment: Best would likely be two structures used together. http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/136254/what-data-structure-should-i-use-for-this-caching-strategy

Comment: @RufusL When creating the structure you would give something like a `Func<TKey,Tvalue>` and if the object is not in cache(because purged) it would call the Func with the Key, store it in his cache and return the item

Comment: Seems you need to implement a class which consists of LinkedList and Dictionary. When you access to an existing item, it moves to the end of the list. Otherwise, the first item from the list is removed.

Comment: @TamasIonut Do you have one specific class in mind? The thing is that if one object is ACCESSED, it has to go up in the list again

Comment: This is a fair implementation: http://geekswithblogs.net/blackrob/archive/2014/09/01/circular-buffer-in-c.aspx

Comment: @hatchet I will take a look. I'm not familiar with the linked list. How do you "move" node of position?

Comment: @J4N - I made a series of 3 posts giving an implementation of an LRU cache class showing the dictionary/linked list pairing, and a google search will find quite a few more. http://blog.softwx.net/2012/06/exploring-linkedlists-via-lru-caches.html

Comment: I didn't know the term LRU, it help me a lot with this. You should put this as answer.(and mention there is no existing structure that fit directly)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you describe is called an LRU (Least Recently Used) cache. Many implementations of this pair a Dictionary with a LinkedList. The Dictionary provides the quick keyed access, and the LinkedList provides the ability to quickly remove the oldest element. Those two operations are somewhat at odds with each other, which is why a single structure that satisfies both well is hard to find.

If you search the internet for LRU cache you will find many implementations. I did a [3-post series](http://blog.softwx.net/2012/06/exploring-linkedlists-via-lru-caches.html) on some implementations I did.